# what does numpy.vectorize(lambda x:1 - x^3) do?

Tags: python, numpy, julia

I'm new to python and also to numpy package. I was wondering what does this specific line really do.

`a = numpy.vectorize(lambda x:1 - x^3)`

I've searched about vectorize function but didn't really get what it does.

I'm familiar with julia if there is any instance in julia that does what this line does I could understand it faster and better.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: `numpy.vectorize()` is conceptually similar to `map()` You pass in a function that acts on a single value and it returns a function that when passed a vector, returns a vector with values resulting from the given initializing function. It might help to also know that `^` is bitwise XOR

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda

Comment: `np.vectorize` takes a function that only works with scalar inputs, and returns one that should work with array inputs.  Where did you find this?  That `lambda` alread works with an array `x` input, so all `vectorize` is doing is making things much slower.  For a beginner there are more import parts of `numpy` to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `lambda` on Python is used to declare an anonymous function. So the statement

`a = lambda x: 1 - x**3`

Is mathematically equivalent to:

`a(x) = 1 - x^3`

The vectorize function on NumPy is used to apply a function element-wise in an array. So, suppose you have an array `x` with elements `[1,2,3]`, the result of `a` on `x` is:

```
[1-1^3,1-2^3,1-3^3]
```

I am not an expert in Julia, but I believe that the equivalent would be this:

```
a = function(x)
        1 - x^3
    end
```

And then, if you want to it use the same way Python would after the vectorize function, you would add a "." after the function name:

```
a.([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I completely got what it does.

Comment: `a(x) = 1 - x^3` is in fact valid Julia, and is preferable to `a = ...` (as the binding to `a` is const). The dot in `a.([1,2,3])` is correct, or else you could define `a(x) = 1 .- x.^3` to make a function which will work on arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

The closest Julia equivalent would be this:

```
julia> a = Base.Broadcast.BroadcastFunction(x -> 1 - x^3)
Base.Broadcast.BroadcastFunction(var"#1#2"())

julia> a([1,2,3])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
   0
  -7
 -26
```

Although you rarely construct `BroadcastFunction`s directly, as it's usually easier to use broadcasting syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer - in Julia you use just dot operator to vectorize code so when applying a lambda to all elements of a vector one would do:

```
julia> (x -> 1 - x^3).([1,2,3])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
   0
  -7
 -26
```

In the code above the dot symbol `.` makes the lambda to be applied to every element of the vector.